# Not able to disable buttons using custom angular directive

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-material

I'm trying to disable the buttons during AJAX requests.

The flow has 3 files,

1. `app.interceptor.ts` <-- toggles the `isAjaxInProgress` observable in shared.service.ts
2. `shared.service.ts` <-- hosts isAjaxInProgress observable
3. `disable-during-ajax.directive.ts` <-- subscribes to the isAjaxInProgress; if true disables the button

==============================================================

shared.service.ts:

```
private _isAnyRequestInProgress = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
isAnyRequestInProgress$ = this._isAnyRequestInProgress.asObservable();
```

app.interceptor.ts:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
this.sharedService.isAnyRequestInProgress = true;
// delay of few seconds
return next.handle(request).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.sharedService.isAnyRequestInProgress = false));
}
```

disable-during-ajax.directive.ts:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[disableDuringAjax]',
})

constructor(private el: ElementRef){}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sharedService.isAnyRequestInProgress$.subscribe(
      bool => this.el.nativeElement.disabled = bool
    );
  }
```

==============================================================

Utilisation:

```
<button type="submit" mat-flat-button color="primary" disableDuringAjax>Action</button>
```

Any other approach is also welcomed.

Comment: Can you post an example of that on stackblitz?

Comment: @JanosVinceller, here's a link, https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-moore-bw94y, and it is working perfectly fine. I guess I'll have to scrutinise the imports, declarations and providers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to tap straight into the Observable and not use a directive.

Component:

```js
buttonDisabled$: Observable<boolean>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.buttonDisabled$ = this.sharedService.isAnyRequestInProgress$;
}
```

Template:

```html
<button type="submit" mat-flat-button color="primary" [disabled]="buttonDisabled$ | async">Action</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, Will for the response. Is there any particular reason for this recommendation? This functionality will be used across components many times at multiple places. So I believe it is not practical to add the same snippet everywhere.

Comment: If it is to be used in multiple places, I’d make a component rather than a directive, taking for example the button text as an @Input. It may well be possible to do this with a directive, but I reckon a component makes more sense.